# Submenu or navigation bar at 10th level

Tags: menu, mega-menu

[image]I am designing the webpage for content management system where user have to search content at submenu level(1-10th level sometime) .How to arrange menu navigation on the page .Please advice.

Comment: I advice you to reconsider your information architecture if your navigation needs to have ten levels.

Comment: As it stands, this question lacks the context needed to help you. Could you include some wireframe sketches of where you expect this navigation to go and what it is expected to do?

Comment: Andrew Just attached the wireframe where each menu level leads to submenu its like peeling an onion.Can you suggest me organize way to handle

Comment: yes, if you have ten levels something has gone catastrophically wrong

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are gone extreme of using sub-level menu. Navigation that are specific and do not overlap are the easiest to understand. This cuts both ways: In deep hierarchies, when there are only a few navigation categories on each level, they tend to be more generic and, thus, more confusing. A flatter hierarchy with more navigation categories at each level usually has more-specific labels that are easier to understand; but in broad hierarchies with a very large number of items, there is often some conceptual overlap between at least a few of the navigation categories. Users can also become overwhelmed with long, cluttered menus.

Source: [Nelson Norman Group article "Flat vs. Deep Website Hierarchies"](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/flat-vs-deep-hierarchy/)

I would suggest to reconsider your IA and use given below methods:

1. [Card sorting](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/card-sorting-how-many-users-to-test/)
2. [Tree Testing](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/tree-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [OSX Finder can be viewed using Columns](http://osxdaily.com/2010/03/25/setting-the-default-column-size-in-mac-os-x-finder-windows/).
The same Columns approach is used in [Jobs at Apple website](https://jobs.apple.com/us/search?#location&t=0&sb=req_open_dt&so=1&lo=2*Narashino*JPN*670*SPC&pN=0).

If you take this approach, the menu navigation will need to be the full width of the container.